# How to show layer navigation filter in top of list.phtml (magento 1)?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to show layer navigation filter in top of list product page. in dropdown filter i'll prefer. Thanks in advanced.

Finally this code is work in my theme.

```
<reference name="product_list">
  <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.toplayer" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.toplayer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <catalog_category_layered>
            <reference name="left">
                <action method="unsetChild"><alias>catalog.leftnav</alias></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="product_list">
                <action method="insert"><blockName>catalog.leftnav</blockName></action>
            </reference>
        </catalog_category_layered>
    </layout>
```

Add above code into your local.xml file or edit catalog.xml file

Now need to edit

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
or you need to edit that file into your theme

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav'); ?>
```

add that line into top of phtml

Comment: Thanks for help but this is not working in my theme.